# When launching script in background I get two processes running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, background-process

I came across a weird scenario that is stumping me.

I have a script that I launch in the background with an & 
example:

```
root@# some_script.sh &
```

After running it, I do a ps -ef | grep some_script and I see TWO processes running where the 2nd process keeps getting an different PID but it's Parent is the process that I started (like the parent process is spawning children that die off - but this was never written in the code).
example:

```
root@# ps -ef | grep some_script.sh
root      4696 17882  0 13:30 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./some_script.sh
root      4778  4696  0 13:30 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./some_script.sh
root@# ps -ef | grep some_script.sh
root      4696 17882  0 13:30 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./some_script.sh
root      4989  4696  0 13:30 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./some_script.sh
```

What gives here? It seems to be messing up the output and functionality of the script too and basically makes it a never ending process (when I have a defined start and stop in the script).

the script:
`
    #! /bin/bash

```
# Set Global Variables
LOGDIR="/srv/script_logs"
OUTDIR="/srv/audits"
BUCKET_LS=$OUTDIR"/LSOUT_"$i"_"$(date +%d%b%Y)".TXT"
MYCMD1="aws s3api list-objects --bucket viddler-flvs"
MYCMD2="--starting-token"
MAX_ITEMS="--max-items 10000"
MYSTARTING_TOKEN='""'
rm tokenlog.txt flv_out.txt

while [[ $MYSTARTING_TOKEN != "null" ]]
do
# First - Get the token for the next batch
CMD_PRE="$MYCMD1 $MAX_ITEMS $MYCMD2 $MYSTARTING_TOKEN"
MYSTARTING_TOKEN=($($CMD_PRE | jq -r .NextToken))
echo $MYSTARTING_TOKEN >> tokenlog.txt
# Now - get the values of the files for the existing batch
# First - re-run the batch and get the file values we want
MYOUT2=$($CMD_PRE | (jq ".Contents[] | {Key, Size, LastModified,StorageClass }"))
echo $MYOUT2 | sed 's/[{},"]//g;s/   /\n/g;s/StorageClass://g;s/LastModified://g;s/Size://g;s/Key://g;s/^ *//g;s/ *$//g' >> flv_out.txt
#echo $STARTING_TOKEN
done
```

`

Comment: How does your script look?

Comment: I would need to see the code in some_script.sh to help with this.

Comment: What does `jobs` report?

Comment: Added the script I am using

Comment: jobs comes back blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have

```
(
some shell instructions
)
```

inside of your .sh
This syntax executes commands in the new process (but command line would be the same).

Comment: That, or shell code in a pipeline (e.g. `somecommand | while read; do... done`); this will also run in a subshell.

Comment: I see it being more of the pipe in my command - Sometimes it's the basics that get ya ;) Thanks everyone!